# Как загрузить данные порциями через HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net

**Задача**

Вообще, это клон [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46190444/how-to-upload-data-by-portions-via-httpwebrequest) на stackoverflow.com. (Просто там никто не отвечает)

Необходимо загрузить данные по частям через один http-запрос и показать изменения прогресса после каждой загрузки (физическая отправка данных через интернет). (Неважно, как я буду показывать прогресс, можно просто в консоль выводить).

**Код**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

...

public static void UploadData()
{
    const string data = "simple string";
    byte[] buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(data);

    // благодаря http://www.posttestserver.com все сразу работает
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 " + 
                  "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.224 Safari/534.10";
    req.Accept = "application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset", "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
    req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;            
    req.SendChunked = true;            

    int bytesRead = buffer.Length;
    const int chunkSize = 3;
    Stream s = req.GetRequestStream();
    for (int offset = 0; offset < bytesRead; offset += chunkSize)
    {
        int bytesLeft = bytesRead - offset;
        int bytesWrite = bytesLeft > chunkSize ? chunkSize : bytesLeft;
        s.Write(buffer, offset, bytesWrite);
    }
    s.Close(); // ВАЖНО: только здесь будут отправлены данные через сеть
}
```

**Важно**

Каким бы ни были параметры `SendChuncked`, `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` и `ContentLength` данные по сети никогда не посылаются после каждой записи в поток запроса (все смотрел через Fiddler).

**Вопрос**

Как отправлять данные (физически) после каждой записи в поток запроса (вызов метода Write)?

*Ограничения:*

- .Net 2.0;
- использование только HttpWebRequest (WebClient не подходит).

Comment: А разве Fiddler не ждет пока данные отправятся полностью, что бы показать полный запрос/ответ? `Stream.Flush` пробовали после `Stream.Write`?

Comment: Если вызывать Flush после Write, то Fiddler никакой активности не показывает. Fiddler показывает активность только после вызова Close().

Comment: И да, возможно, Fiddler ждет, пока данные отправятся полностью, что бы показать полный запрос/ответ. Но если смотреть через http debuger (http://www.httpdebugger.com/), то поведение такое же. Возможно httpdebugger ведет себя так же как fiddler. Мне просто нужно каким-то образом удостовериться, что данные действительно отправляются после каждого вызова Write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает как вы ожидаете. Я использовал Microsoft Network Monitor, это качественная низкоуровневая утилита, к тому же бесплатная (в отличии от httpdebugger).
Останавливал программу в дебаге (переключил на .NET 2.0):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Network Monitor показывает каждую отправку по 3 байта (я взял строку подлиннее):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например здесь отправлен текст "ple" (sim**ple** string):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]